# Running classmexer for a tomcat application?

Tags: java, tomcat6, javaagents, transactionmanager

I'm trying to use classmexer-0.3.jar with tomcat to get Object sizes for my web application.  However when the method is invoked I get the following error message:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Ljavax/transaction/TransactionManager;
        java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
        java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2308)
        java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1760)
        com.javamex.classmexer.MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf0(MemoryUtil.java:197)
        com.javamex.classmexer.MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(MemoryUtil.java:104)
        com.javamex.classmexer.MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(MemoryUtil.java:80)
```

What can I do to fix this?  I assume I need a jar with the class TransactionManager but I don't know which one.

My project is built using Maven in eclipse for development and run from a unix server with Jenkins.

Cheers,

Alexei Blue.

Edit:
Looks to be working now for more basic objects which suggest the setup is right.  I think the problem was caused when calling MemoryUtil.deepMemoryUsageOf(Obj) where obj contains a Google LoadingCache.  It seems I maybe missing some source for that, any ideas on what that source maybe?

Comment: can post configuration xml file?? something like context.xml..

Answer (score 0):

Use this service: 
http://findjar.com/class/javax/transaction/TransactionManager.html

It's very helpful in finding dependencies.